# Deleting Row From GridView With Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview

Whats wrong with my code? I want to remove a row from gridview when I click delete hyperlink(button).

It shows that the value is out of range. What Should i do?

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e) 
{
  cn = new SqlConnection(conStr);
  delCmd = new SqlCommand();
  cn = new SqlConnection(conStr);
  cn.Open();

  //delCmd.Connection = cn;

  delCmd = new SqlCommand("spDelEmployee",cn);
  delCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  delCmd.CommandText = "spDelEmployee";
  delCmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values);

  cn.Open();
  delCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  DataBind();
  cn.Close();
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spDelEmployee
@EmployeeID int
AS
DELETE FROM Employed WHERE EmployeeID=@EmployeeID
RETURN
```

Comment: In your code is not clear if you have set the `DataKeyNames` property. Without it I think you could not use `DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a specific cell in a GridView. In your code, you can just replace:

```
GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values
```

with:

```
GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[xxx].Text
```

where xxx is the 0-indexed column number that contains EmployeeID.

Comment: The line of code that u provided doesnt work.   `Convert.ToInt32((GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1]).ToString());` this shows that Input string was not in the correct format.

Comment: Sorry about that. See corrected answer. Be careful to use parentheses, not square brackets.

Comment: Error 1 Non-invocable member 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.Rows' cannot be used like a method.



`delCmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Text;`


Word Rows is underlined showing mistake

Comment: Doh! Square brackets, not parentheses.

Comment: When I click delete button Exception appears "Input string was not in a correct format."  I'll try to fix it. 

tho ' Thanks for ur time and helping me)

Answer (score 0):

Heres how I solved my problem) It woks.

```
  protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e) 
    {

        cn = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        cn.Open();

        delCmd = new SqlCommand("spDelEmployee",cn);
        delCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


        object id = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[em.EmployeeID].Text.ToString();

        delCmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(id);

        delCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```